# How to configure SVN server for my own project

Tags: svn, version-control

- I work with a team on an Android project using Eclipse IDE,
- We need to use a version control and we need to access the repository remotely,
- I have no experience using or installing servers, a little experience using SVN on Windows, but I still have problems connecting to it remotely.
- I need to use *no-ip.com* service to change my IP, however; I failed to make VisualSVN Server to work with no-ip. What options do I have?

The best thing is to get it work with Windows if not, I have another computer that is running Ubuntu 12.4.1, I have installed apache2svn on it trying to get it work, the svn is installed, I went through tutorials to configure accessing protocols, but I can't figure out how to access it remotely from another computer?
Can someone tell me the steps I need to get this job done and I can do my search for each step? (Please explain each step as some keywords or phrases I may not be familiar with)

EDIT:
Also worth noting, that my company has a website hosted on a remote server,  can we use it as a repo? and how? It's running Linux

Comment: If you have a small amount of experience server-side, why not get someone else to do the leg work ? google code, source forge, etc if its open source, github, bitbucket etc if it's closed source. Might be easier for you.

Comment: github works with closed source? oh I thought if I go this way my project will has to be open source

Comment: For free, it only supports open source, but if you pay (its not a lot at all) you can have private repositories. Bitbucket i think is even free for private repos but only with 1 user (unless you pay, of course, and it also isn't very much).

Comment: for more info about github pricing: https://github.com/plans

Comment: Thanks, but I can't really pay, I know it isn't much but I still can't.. so I guess I will have to do it myself

Comment: ok. It'll cost way less than the disks, your time, backup, network bandwidth, and everything else you'll need though.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to need a big storage, Am I? Time is okay, network bandwidth, I already have that.. Thank you for your advice tho

Comment: You're a developer, right? Buying a github plan would be MUCH cheaper than setting up your own server.

Comment: Beware! :) I see that github kites pounced on in the comments...

Comment: bitbucket, hosted svn, whatever works... Just don't do it yourself if you're a developer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your question can be reworded like ***"How can I setup a Subversion server over HTTP(S) to work through a dynamic DNS provider?"*** Why do you even need the dynamic DNS service? You should definitely consider obtaining a dedicated IP address to lighten the burden.

However there should be no issues with any SVN server solution working through a dynamic DNS, it's similar to setting up any other web service to be accessible from the Internet with a dynamic DNS service:

- You have to make sure that the public IP address is assigned to the
  correct internal IP of the SVN Server machine on your LAN,
- Check port-forwarding on your network hardware.

For Subversion server solution in Windows environment you can consider [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) which you've mentioned already. The initial installation and configuration of VisualSVN Server is really easy and takes a couple of seconds to complete.

Answering to the Q in the edit: I don't think that you really need or want to store repositories remotely on a hosted remote server.

Since you are novice Subversion user I strongly advise you to consider the [SVNBook (Version Control with Subversion)](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/). It's the best source of Subversion-related knowledge and the following chapters introduce the most common version-control practices and help you familiarize yourself with Apache Subversion:

- [**1. Fundamental Concepts**](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/basic/)
- [**2. Basic Usage**](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question must be splitted into **two** *unrelated questions* really

1. How to install and configure VisualSVN Server?
2. How to use any local service with no-ip?

BTW, "need to use no-ip.com to change my IP" is wrong assumption or definition. In order to be clean: no-ip allow you to use **permanent hostname** with **dynamic (changeable) IP-address** for all and any services, which are running on your host and accessible via URL, for external world. This task does not related in any form with svn - it's task of independent *client of DDNS-service* on your Windows-host

I'll suggest to have working no-ip before VisualSVN Server, i.e

- select name for your host
- install, configure and run needed no-ip software in order to have `ping myc00lname.no-ip.com` without errors after any amount of reconnects and IP-changes

After it [install and run VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/) and you http(s)-served Subversion server will be accessible on URL of your hostname:serverport (selected at install stage)